# How to auto fill other websites which I donot own

Tags: javascript, web, autofill

I need to fill a website which I donot own many times. I want to write a script or software to let my information fill the website's form. I know how script like "document.getElementByID( "zipCode" ).value = "98105";" works. But I donot have access to the server side of the website. How can I fill these forms automatically by simply access the  client side. Thank you.

Comment: If you want to fill a form and submit it too, the you should have a look at greasemonkey, it used to inject custom scripts on domains you want it to. Else, there are auto fill extensions for Chrome and Firefox, use those.

Answer (score 0):

There are firefox addons for the same:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-forms/reviews/

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/autofill-262804/